# Pandas df, detecting dates

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas df as follows:

```
Name    Cust1   Cust2   Cust3      Cust4

ABC      Y       N       Y       2022-01-01
DEF      N       N       N          N
```

I am looking to detect if a date is in a row  for `Cust1, Cust2, Cust3 and Cust4` and if so create a column to populate that date.
So that output would look like

```
Name    Date

ABC    2022-01-01
DEF      na
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?
I am trying to do `df.iloc[:,1:].apply(np.where<xxx>` but not sure of how to approach this from here on.

Thanks!

Comment: If possible multiple dates per rows what is expected ouput?

Comment: Good catch, in that case I want to take the latest date (as in most recent date). Thanks!

Comment: Performance is important?

Comment: Not really...performance is secondary here..not many rows of data. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten your dataframe then keep the most recent date per Name:

```
to_date = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['Date'], errors='coerce')
out = df.melt('Name', value_name='Date').assign(Date=to_date) \
        .groupby('Name', as_index=False)['Date'].max()
print(out)

# Output
  Name       Date
0  ABC 2022-01-01
1  DEF        NaT
```

Answer (score 1):

Try convert values of all columns to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'` for missing values if not datetimelike values and then get maximal dates per rows:

```
f = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce')
df = df.set_index('Name').apply(f).max(axis=1).reset_index(name='Date')
print (df)
  Name       Date
0  ABC 2022-01-01
1  DEF        NaT
```

Alternative solution:

```
f = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce')
df = df[['Name']].join(df.iloc[:,1:].apply(f).max(axis=1).rename('Date'))
print (df)
  Name       Date
0  ABC 2022-01-01
1  DEF        NaT
```